# Issue with BOOST unit_test_framework / Google Test on macOS Mojave

Tags: c++, macos, homebrew, googletest, boost-unit-test-framework

During a build process (unit tests) there are a bunch of errors like:
 "*error: no member named '**xxx**' in the global namespace
using::**xxx**;*" ('**xxx**' is a type, e.g. uint8_t).

DETAILS:

- in case if I include only <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>, the source of error is in the file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdint
- in case if I include <boost/cstdint.hpp> before , the source of error is in the file /usr/local/include/boost/cstdint.hpp

ENVIRONMENT:

- macOS Mojave
- compiler: clang
- CXX_STANDARD: 11 / 14
- boost v.1.67.0_1 (installed using homebrew to default location - usr/local/Cellar/)

**UPD:** The same issue (with cstdint) happens with using Google Test (1.8.1)

Answer (score 0):

After some time spent with this issue, I reinstall the operating system. 
Now I have Boost and Google Test working in parallel.

I can't be sure for 100% about the reason for the issue but I compared the `usr/local/include` folder before and after reinstallation. I found that there are many `.cpp` and `.h` files and `cstdint.hpp` is among them. Now `usr/local/include` folder contains only symbolic links for boost, gmock and gtest.